# How database engine of SQL swap two columns values?

Tags: update, database-engine

I want to swap values of two columns in a table, And I found that in SQL we can do that by using Update:

```sql
update the_table set first_name = last_name, last_name = first_name;
```

It works But I wonder How SQL can do that without **overwrite** data in a column of other column?

Comment: Are you asking how it can physically be done that way, or are you asking what in the statement implies that it *should* be done that way? Or are you asking for confirmation that it does always work?

Comment: @Charlieface I would like to get answers to all of these three questions you provide.

Comment: Not unique to SQL, you can do the same in python

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkrainin But in Python you either need a temporary variable or a temporary tuple value

Comment: You can do `(a, b) = (b, a)` in python @Bergi.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, that's the "temporary tuple value" I mentioned, and this syntax is not what the OP is using in SQL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@mustaccio has [answered](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/317506/220697) how this is **physically** implemented.

---

The **logical** specification is as follows:

The columns on the right side of the `=` in an `UPDATE SET` statement **must** come from the values before the update is applied. Therefore it is simple to swap the values, because the right side always refers to the old values.

Another way to see why is to consider the equivalent rewriting of your statement:

```
update the_table 
set (first_name, last_name) = (last_name, first_name);
```

This is not implemented by all SQL products but it is equivalent according to the SQL standard and where it has been implemented, it works exactly as yours.

---

As to whether it is guaranteed: **yes it is.** It is mandated by the SQL specification, and as far as I know, most DBMSs implement this requirement (MySQL and derived/forked products eg MariaDB are an exception and do not implement the standard correctly in this case).

Comment: For those like me who got curious about your MySQL comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37649/87698. That's... unexpected.

Answer (score 6):

It's because each row is processed in its entirety, as a whole, not column by column. The simplified sequence goes like this:

1. Fetch a matching row.
2. Retrieve current values of the referenced columns.
3. Update columns as requested.
4. Write the row back.
5. Go to 1.

The SQL standard (at least the version I have access to) stipulates the behaviour in these terms (emphasis mine):

> 9. S[et]C[lause] is evaluated for each row of T[able] prior to the invocation of any <triggered action> caused by the update of any row of T.
> 10. The <update source> of each <set clause> contained in S[et]C[lause]L[ist] is **effectively evaluated for each row of T before any row of T is updated**.
> 11. For each subject row, a candidate new row is constructed by copying the subject row and updating it as specified by each <set clause> contained in SCL by applying the General Rules of Subclause 14.15, “<set clause list>”.

Comment: I like the explanation but the simplification would fail to explain a similar question about swapping values between two rows. (perhaps add a note?)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Why would that be any different? If you have a self-join to pair the rows, it will retrieve all the columns from the source row (step 2), then update the columns in the destination row (step 3 and 4).

Comment: @Barmar, it shouldn't be different and it isn't in practice. But the "simplified sequence" as described here seems to be imply that the changes are applied row by row.  (we modify row A with the value from row B, write the changes back to disk and then proceed to modify row B). That wouldn't work as wanted.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Ah right, I was thinking "assign", not "swap".

Answer (score 0):

I have used the answers above but none of them are working. Because it automatically updates one and copies the same value to the other.
It can be related to the version of the SQL we are using.

**I recommend creating an empty column to use as an intermediate copy buffer.**